# Chronicle queue reader (ExcerptTailer) doesn't read messages, returns false even there are lots of messages in the queue

Tags: java, chronicle, chronicle-queue

Hi I'm using the following queue versions,

```
chronicle-queue.version : 4.5.15
chronicle-wire.version : 1.7.14
```

My Chronicle reader got stuck at some point (index 74204158352345 ) and readDocument returns false after each call, but my chronicle writer was continuing writing messages to the same queue.
The reader code is like follows,

```
ChronicleQueue queue = ChronicleQueueBuilder.single(chroniclePath).build();
excerptTailer = queue.createTailer();
excerptTailer.readDocument(document);// Marshallable document
```

I'm calling readDocument inside a while loop.
There was no chronicle errors in the logs. But my code brakes on the last message from chronicle queue because the message was incomplete. I got only some bytes of the last message and there after readDocument returns false. But there are messages continuously writing to the queue.

My writer code,

```
public void init() {
    queue = ChronicleQueueBuilder.single(chroniclePath).build();
    appender = queue.acquireAppender();
}

public void write(T document) {
    appender.writeDocument(document);
}
public void destroy() {
    if (queue !=null && queue.isClosed()) {
        queue.close();
    }
}
```

I tried upgrading the queue to the latest (`4.5.27 & 1.7.32`) versions in my local machine and ran the reader on the same production cq4 file(5GB) again I got the same issue but with an error on console (saw the same clues in Thread dump also)

```
Exception in thread "Chronicle Reader" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap.getEntry(ThreadLocal.java:414)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap.access$000(ThreadLocal.java:298)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:163)
    at java.lang.StringCoding.deref(StringCoding.java:63)
    at java.lang.StringCoding.encode(StringCoding.java:330)
    at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:918)
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.checkAccess(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.canWrite(File.java:796)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts$StoreTailer.isReadOnly(SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts.java:798)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts$StoreTailer.inACycle(SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts.java:1006)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts$StoreTailer.checkMoveToNextCycle(SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts.java:1055)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts$StoreTailer.inACycle(SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts.java:1007)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts$StoreTailer.checkMoveToNextCycle(SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts.java:1055)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts$StoreTailer.inACycle(SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts.java:1007)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts$StoreTailer.checkMoveToNextCycle(SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts.java:1055)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts$StoreTailer.inACycle(SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts.java:1007)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts$StoreTailer.checkMoveToNextCycle(SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts.java:1055)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts$StoreTailer.inACycle(SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts.java:1007)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts$StoreTailer.checkMoveToNextCycle(SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts.java:1055)
etc...
```

In the new version the readDocument method got hung. May be hung on recursion.
What may be the problem, Please help.

Comment: Related https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue/issues/347

Comment: the fix you gave removed the error stacktrace but I'm still unable to read the cq4 file after the same index. returns false again.